# Correct cursor position in Vim

Tags: vim, editing

Consider this situation:

```
    foo
A   B
```

I just entered "foo" (notice the indent) and moved to the next line. The cursors is in position B. I'm done with editing and I hit `Esc` which brings my cursor to position A. How can I exit the insertion mode and keep the cursor at position B, or jump immedietly from A to B?

This vim's behavior is annoying when I'm editing something deep in a function, with few indents.

Comment: Please see this duplicate on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/120754/how-do-i-make-vims-autoindent-not-drop-trailing-spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you're at the end of the document, `o` will put you into insert mode at the correct indent level on the next line down. If you're on a row that contains nothing but a newline, `cc` will erase anything in the line and put you into insert mode at the correct indent level.

Comment: I'm aware of `o` behavior. I tried `cc` and it doesn't seem to work as you say in the situation I described.

Comment: cc seems to work for some files like C or javascript but not others